# How to give particles the emitter body's colours at points of ejection using Normal data?

Tags: particles, shaders, normals, hair, shader-nodes

I have an Emitter object shaded using its mesh's Normal data and doesn't have a texture applied. I want the particles it emit to inherit colours from their point of ejection but cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

The below node setting is the closest result I could obatain. But on close inspection you may note the particles having the wrong colour upon emission and eventually changing colours as they rise up.

How can I get a precise result?

[image: Emitter shading]

[image: Particle shading]

Comment: You can do it in Cycles with an Image Texture but I'm not sure it is possible with a procedural texture, another way around would be to create 2 particle systems, one for each color

Comment: Hey @moonboots Yes that would be some ways to do it! But I'd prefer not to complicate it with an image texture or multiple particle systems (I already have 3 different particle systems emitting a great deal of particles in my actual application). It's already in cycles btw. Please let me know if you later happen to figure out a procedural method. Thank you!